# Neo4j & JPype Installation Issue

Tags: python, neo4j

I use Ubuntu 10.10 and before continuing with the installation, I installed JPype and openjdk-6-jdk & all its dependencies using synaptic.

I proceeded with the install of Neo4j & Python as mentioned on:

```
http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j.py/0.1-SNAPSHOT/
```

But when I did

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

in the neo4j-python folder, it gave the following error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 146, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 134, in main
    args[attr] = pom[attr]
  File "/home/aman/Softwares/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    element)
  File "/home/aman/Softwares/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return self.pattern.sub(lambda match:self[match.groupdict()['var']],
  File "/home/aman/Softwares/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    element = self.parent[path]
  File "/home/aman/Softwares/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    return replacement.get(path, lambda s,x:x)(self, self.__pom[path])
  File "/home/aman/Softwares/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(path)
KeyError: 'project.artifactId'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution might work: https://gist.github.com/809425

For other ways of using Neo4j with Python see http://www.delicious.com/neo4j/drivers+python and maybe http://www.delicious.com/neo4j/python to get more information.