# Constrained minimization of multivariate function using Jython

Tags: python, jython, mathematical-optimization, jython-2.5

I have a python program running under Jython (to use a third party Java API), inside which I would like to calculate a constrained minimization of a multivariate function.

Scipy has a module for this that works perfectly ([`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize)) but unfortunately you cannot use scipy within Jython. Does anyone know of a good library/any other way to do this in Jython? If I could just run this under Jython, I'd be all set:

```
def func(x, sign=1.0):
    """ Objective function -- minimize this """
    return sign*(2*x[0]*x[1] + 2*x[0] - x[0]**2 - 2*x[1]**2)

def func_deriv(x, sign=1.0):
    """ Derivative of objective function """
    dfdx0 = sign*(-2*x[0] + 2*x[1] + 2)
    dfdx1 = sign*(2*x[0] - 4*x[1])
    return np.array([ dfdx0, dfdx1 ])

cons = ({'type': 'eq',
         'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[0]**3 - x[1]]),
         'jac' : lambda x: np.array([3.0*(x[0]**2.0), -1.0])}, #partial derivative of fun
        {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[1] - 1]),
         'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0.0, 1.0])})   #partial derivative of fun

res = minimize(func, [-1.0,1.0], args=(-1.0,), jac=func_deriv, 
               method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, options={'disp': True})
```

Thanks! -Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most optimal solution to your particular use case as you already have your application in Jython but `JPype` ([link](http://jpype.sourceforge.net)) allows a CPython program to talk to a program running on JVM, I haven't tried it my self but found a hello world example [here](http://www.thenumber42.net/2008/03/31/how-to-use-jpype/).

Basically you make your Java class, compile it into a jar and then in CPython do

```
import jpype
import os.path

jarpath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'build/jar')
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % jarpath)

# get the class
hello_world = jpype.JClass('com.stackoverflow.HelloWorld')
t = hello_world()  # create an instance of the class
t.helloWorld("Say hello")  # try to call one of the class methods
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

I realise though that inverts your application logic. The other option would be to use `subprocess` and serialise the inputs/outputs.

**UPDATE**

I came across a similar problem recently and decided to give `JPype` a go and can now say that it's well worth using, although there are some issues installing it at least on OSX, see help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525193/cannot-install-jpype-on-os-x-lion-to-use-with-neo4j) (some of the JVM paths need to be altered in `setup.py`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. Subprocess is always an option if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is using Jython, you can use Slsqp4j to perform the solving natively on the JVM and bypass writing SciPy code entirely. Slsqp4j is a Java wrapper around the SLSQP solver included in SciPy. The api is very similar to SciPy's. It's hosted here:
https://github.com/skew-opensource/slsqp4j

(disclosure: I am the author)

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, [see "Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Examples of how to use a library would be greatly appreciated. This is also explained in [promoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).