# Installing jpype in Mountain Lion

Tags: java, python, macos, jpype

I am trying to install jpype in Mountain Lion. I followed all the steps suggested in this post: [How to install JPype on OS X Lion to use with Neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525193/how-to-install-jpype-on-os-x-lion-to-use-with-neo4j)

However, there is a glitch with Mountain Lion. I have modified the `setupMacOSX()` function as follows:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/
```

But when I run `$ sudo python setup.py install` I get the following error:

```
src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
```

I have located the jni.h header here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h
```

But since jni.h is not part of Mountain Lion, I have not figured out how to modify the setup.py file to fix the bug. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

This is on a system running OSX 10.8.5.

I modified the setup.py for `JPype-0.5.4.2` and added an element to the end of the `self.includeDirs` list which is created in the function `setupInclusion`. This function is declared at line 61 for this particular version of JPype.

```
     def setupInclusion(self):
          self.includeDirs = [
              self.javaHome+"/include", 
              self.javaHome+"/include/"+self.jdkInclude,
              "src/native/common/include",
              "src/native/python/include",

              #I added this line below. The folder contains a jni.h
              "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/"
          ]
```

Finally I ran `pip install ~/Path/To/JPype-folder/` and the installation was successful.